# Can't get live TV to work in openelec

Tags: tv

I am struggling trying to get Live TV working under openelec 3.2.0. I am using a Hauppauge 1191 WinTV-HVR-950Q tuner card, and it works under Windows 8 using the bundled software.

However, tvheadend plugin isn't finding any channels.

I also attempted running `w_scan -c US -a N /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0 -A2` and got the following output. I'd appreciate any help, I've been trying to get this working for days.

```
w_scan version 20121111 (compiled for DVB API 5.10)
WARNING: VDR up to version 1.7.13 doesn't support ATSC.
        Changing output format to 'vdr-1.7.x'
using settings for UNITED STATES
ATSC
QAM US/CA
scan type TERRCABLE_ATSC, channellist 2
output format vdr-1.7
WARNING: could not guess your codepage. Falling back to 'UTF-8'
output charset 'UTF-8', use -C <charset> to override
Info: using DVB adapter auto detection.
        /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0 -> TERRCABLE_ATSC "Auvitek AU8522 QAM/8VSB Frontend": good :-)
Using TERRCABLE_ATSC frontend (adapter /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0)
-_-_-_-_ Getting frontend capabilities-_-_-_-_
Using DVB API 5.a
frontend 'Auvitek AU8522 QAM/8VSB Frontend' supports
INVERSION_AUTO
8VSB
QAM_64
QAM_256
FREQ (54.00MHz ... 858.00MHz)
-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
57000: QAM256(time: 00:00)
63000: QAM256(time: 00:03)
69000: QAM256(time: 00:05)
...
...
...
831000: QAM256(time: 06:46)
837000: QAM256(time: 06:48)
843000: QAM256(time: 06:51)
849000: QAM256(time: 06:53)

ERROR: Sorry - i couldn't get any working frequency/transponder
Nothing to scan!!
```

Comment: *"I am using a Hauppauge 1191 WinTV-HVR-950Q tuner card"* -- That isn't a "card"; it's a **USB adapter**. Before you can run `w_scan` you need to ensure that the tuner was properly recognized and installed.  Check the syslog: use the `dmesg` command.  The tuner might need a firmware download.

Comment: I am not seeing anything in the log that indicates it might be failing. Here's the log http://pastebin.com/FpdeUzXm

Comment: *"I am not seeing anything in the log that indicates it might be failing."*  -- But I see something.  There's a line **"xc5000: Firmware has not been loaded previously"** that is repeating at least twice.  Rather unusual that there is no attempt to actually request/load the firmware! Did you run the `w_scan` and then check the syslog for **new** messages?  Check out the [LinuxTV page for your USB tuner](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-950Q) on needed firmware.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like lack of firmware was to blame. I ended up building an Ubuntu VM to test this, and finally got w_scan working after copying the first firmware to /lib/firmware folder. 
Now, I just need to figure out how to do this on openelec. /lib/ appears to be read-only and I struggling trying to figure out how to make it writable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the 950Q running with Openelec. The problem is that the firmware for the USB version requires the following firmware

dvb-fe-xc5000c-4.1.30.7.fw

Once I installed that in the proper firmware directory all worked